# How do I remove meta tags in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have multiple image's meta tag generated by Yoast plugin, The other I have no idea, I'm trying to remove the first meta so that I can be able to get preview images when sharing the post via WhatsApp.

I have looked into the header in WordPress there is no meta tag shown when viewing the source code on browser saw multiple image meta appeared on a single post. website is benjavibe.com

Below is my header tags

```
 <meta property="og:image" content="https://benjavibe.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Usilie.jpg" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://benjavibe.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Music-icon-300x300.png">

    <meta name="description" content="Tanzania Number One Website that give you all trending Entertainment News. New Music and New Videos and Many more." />
    <link rel="canonical" href="https://benjavibe.com/mo-music-ft-galatone-usilie-audio-download/" />
    <meta property="og:locale" content="en_US" />
    <meta property="og:type" content="article" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Mo music ft Galatone - Usilie | Audio Download - BENJA VIBE MUSIC TANZANIA WEBSITE FOR INTERTAINMENT" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="Tanzania Number One Website that give you all trending Entertainment News. New Music and New Videos and Many more." />
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://benjavibe.com/mo-music-ft-galatone-usilie-audio-download/" />

  <meta property="og:image" content="https://benjavibe.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Usilie.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:secure_url" content="https://benjavibe.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Usilie.jpg" />
    <meta property="og:image:width" content="768" />
    <meta property="og:image:height" content="768" />
    <meta property="og:image:alt" content="Mo music ft Galatone - Usilie" />
```

Comment: Try to deactivate all other plugins and activate plugins one by one to see if any other plugin add open graph meta tags by default?

Comment: vignesh I tried deactivating all plugin and saw that the wp booster score was generating but when deactivating the plugin still the og remaining.

Answer (score 1):

I have come with the solution to remove meta which you want to remove from header,
i hope this will helps you.

You can remove some of the header stuff with the following.

```
// remove unncessary header info
function remove_header_meta() {
    remove_action('wp_head', 'rsd_link');
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link');
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');
    remove_action('wp_head', 'start_post_rel_link');
    remove_action('wp_head', 'index_rel_link');
    remove_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link');
}
add_action('init', 'remove_header_meta');
```

The default installation does not include stuff like meta keywords, so that is either a theme or plugin that you are using.

**UPDATED**

Please check update in the following answer

```
add_filter('wpseo_pre_analysis_post_content', 'mysite_opengraph_content');

function mysite_opengraph_content($val) {
   return '';
}
```

**Updated**

```
    function mysite_opengraph_content($val) {
      return preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "", $val); 
     }
    add_filter('wpseo_pre_analysis_post_content', 'mysite_opengraph_content');
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Niket yes I'm using Yoast, that generate the  meta, but when viewing on source code through the browser is see other og meta, the issue is how to remove that and remaining with the Yoast one

Comment: You want to remove from specific page or from whole site

Comment: From the whole site, i want to remain with only one og:image and not multiple og:image

Comment: Allow me some time i will get back to you and really sorry for inconvenience you have.

Comment: thank you Niket, let me have a test with your update

Comment: I have tested the code you provided to us but still the same, I still see multiple og:images                                                                                                             <meta property="og:image" content="https://benjavibe.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/SURE-COVER.jpg" />

Comment: I have checked and found that in your site there is only one image is there in og-image rest are height, width and alt attributes, check given link http://prntscr.com/npag69

Comment: There is another one before the comment of Yoast, Check the link https://benjavibe.com/screen.png

Answer (score 1):

You can use the wpseo_metadesc filter to disable the meta description tag. You’ll need to add the code below to the **functions.php** file of your theme.

```
add_filter( ‘wpseo_metadesc’, ‘__return_false’ );
```

If you need more information about this I would recommend you to follow this blog post

[Remove Yoast SEO Meta Tags](https://solvemethod.com/remove-yoast-seo-meta-tags/)

Comment: shazim I'm not trying to remove meta description tag, my goal is to remove one  og image that appeared twice